# Do I need a PGP key?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption, openpgp

I've recently got familiar with the concept of OpenPGP public-private keys, and how to use GnuPG tool to manage PGP keys. I have three questions:

1- Is it necessary for me to have a PGP (or an OpenPGP) key? I'm an Android programmer, and an ordinary Linux user.

2- If yes, then, do I need only one PGP key, or I will need several keys for different purposes?

3- Is this belief true: Every today's computer user needs having, and using PGP keys?

Answer (score 1):

1. "Is it necessary" depends on your individual needs. PGP lets you:

   - send/receive encrypted text
   - prove that the message came from you / verify where it came from

Are those things necessary for you? If so, then PGP provides a "pretty good" solution.

2. One PGP key is fine.
   For different purposes, you can use:

   - Different UIDs for different email addresses
   - Different subkeys for different devices (if one device gets lost, you can revoke only one subkey instead of your entire identity)
     See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29858) for more detail.
3. Again, this answer depends on the individual's needs. A computer that's used only for media consumption and online shopping will be fine without; the built-in security (SSL/TLS) will cover credit card numbers, etc.

Signing Android apps is an entirely different story.

This has been answered [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4zm8kt/do_you_sign_all_of_your_apps_with_the_same_key_or) , but in short, create a new key (not keystore) for every app that you may one day sell/transfer. Otherwise, you may have to give someone else a key that is able to sign other apps of yours.

Comment: Does the android store really use regular pgp/gpg keys? https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/publishing/app-signing.html says it uses some "Keytool utility"

Comment: @Xen2050 Whoops, I should've been more clear in the post; I didn't mean to imply that it uses PGP, I was only addressing the "I'm an Android programmer" part of the question. I _believe_ android uses some type of [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), but I'd love to learn more about the specifics. Thanks for catching that!